# Probabilistic forwarding of messages to a subset of servers

Tags: algorithm, probability

There are `n` servers (`n` >= 1) and we want to forward a portion of the incoming requests (using a constant `ratio` which is between 0 and 1) to these servers.

The goal is to have a total of `n x ratio` forwarded messages on average, where the chance of selecting each server as the target for receiving a request is approximately the same.

The easy solution is to use `ratio` to filter incoming requests and then forward each request to all `n` servers, which gives us an average of `n x ratio`. What we actually need is to forward a portion of requests to a subset of available servers each time, and still have `n x ratio` as the average number of forwarded requests.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward each request to `n * ratio` of the servers.

If, as is likely, `n * ratio = k` is not a whole number, forward to `floor(k)` or `ceil(k)` servers, with the probability of forwarding to `ceil(k)` being `k - floor(k)`.

In terms of selecting servers just do a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) until you have your selected number of randomly selected servers.